# Authentication issue in service for SOLR 8.11.2

Tags: solr

We want SOLR authentication enabled in SOLR Admin console. So we have enabled Basic authentication in SOLR 8.11.2 version using Security.json file in \solr-8.11.2\server. When we try to access SOLR data from services we are getting Error 401 require authentication.

Could you please let us know on solr configuration to enabling authentication only on SOLR Admin console and to services to access the data (without code changes).

Tried updating Rule-Based Authorization Plugin in Security file for enabling permission on collection. Issue is not resolved